# Based on python.Appending emp details

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to add employee details who is joined newly and verify whether he/she data Present in excel or not. If not there enter and generate a unique I'd for that `employee (uq_id,name,place,dob,dep)` . (this is the task given to me)  using openpyxl in python .

Name        DOB            place      department        unique_id
Harsha      1/1/1991    hyd         IoT                      random no

Next I want to add srinidhi details.While adding I have to verify whether she is there in excel or not.If not there I have to add her details and generate a random unique I'd for her.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your excel template to see how your datasheet looks like?

Comment: I'm trying to add but it's not uploading

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned how your excel file structure looks like,my code below is written on following assumptions:

1.You need to *print* `employee-id` *if it exists* **but** *in case of a duplicate record* *generate a new* `employee-id`

2.The random generator is producing a 10 letter random `employee-id`.

```
import openpyxl 
import random



def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


# Give the location of the file 
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"

#Enter the new Employee's ID you need to check with your existing data for duplicate.
emp_id = input("Enter employee ID")

# workbook object is created 
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 

sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row 

# Loop will print all values 
# of first column  
for i in range(1, m_row + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1) 
    if (cell_obj.value == emp_id):
        print("Employee with that ID already exists")
        emp_id=randomString(10) #here is the length of your random string.
    else:
        print(cell_obj.value)
```

I can help you more if you give the details for your query.

Comment: Im trying to add picture but it's not uploading

Comment: @UshaSri Upload the screenshot here https://imgur.com/ and share the link

Comment: There is no possiblity to sign in for that

Comment: Can I have ur mail I'd plz

Comment: @UshaSri No need to do that, just upload by clicking on `New Post` and then upload the screenshot

Comment: Sorry there is only sign-in feedback help that's it I didn't find new post option

Comment: Okay, now tell me what seems to be the issue? I have given you the program, what more do you need in this?

Comment: Can u see the picture

Comment: @UshaSri Yes I saw that, I mean to say, what is more do you want from the program exactly?

Comment: @Yes, I see the picture

Comment: OK there I uploaded one picture of coding I'm having the doubt does it works without errors